# Is there official confirmation that Crisis on Infinite Earths affected DCEU?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, dc-extended-universe

As it is well know in the arrowverse Crisis on Infinite Earths:

> There’s a cameo of Ezra Miller from DCEU as the flash, explicitly stating a connection between the arrowverse and the DCEU

Has there been any official or unofficial comments as to whether this will be explicitly acknowledged to justify any creative changes on the DCU (like Pattinson’s Batman or any other planned changes?

I’m specifically looking for comments coming from authorised sources (even if the comment itself is not “official” or have been simply opinions by directors, producers or actors themselves even if they’re not word of god).